# reading template JSON file and creating new file with substitutions in bash or Python

Tags: python, json

I want to have a slightly different JSON file for different environments.

If I create a template file with some kind of variables that would then get substituted based on environment variables, what is the simplest way to implement this?

I searched for a python library for templating, and that inevitably leads to HTML templates. Would any of them work with a json file?

I could use `json.load` and then write with `json.dumps`, but how would I do the substitutions?

This task can also be implemented in **bash** instead of **python**.

The file contains swagger documentation.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is placeholders, then open the file, call `.replace` a few times (or use `re.sub` with a function) then use `json.loads` on the generated string.

test.json

```
{"param":  "<param placeholder>"}
```

Then

```
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    template_json = f.read()

after_replace = template_json.replace('<param placeholder>', 'param value')
print(json.loads(after_replace))
```

outputs

```
{'param': 'param value'}
```

Using `re.sub` with a function and a dict:

test.json

```
{
  "param1":  "<param1 placeholder>",
  "param2":  "<param2 placeholder>",
  "param3":  "<param3 placeholder>"
}
```

Then

```
import json
import re

with open('test.json') as f:
    template_json = f.read()

values = {
    'param1': 'param1 value',
    'param2': 'param2 value',
    'param3': 'param3 value'
}

after_replace = re.sub('<(.+?) placeholder>', lambda match: values.get(match.group(1)), template_json)
print(json.loads(after_replace))
```

outputs

```
{'param1': 'param1 value', 'param2': 'param2 value', 'param3': 'param3 value'}
```